# WWW URL redirection since WordPress.com wont host www subdomain name

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've recently moved my blog over to WordPress.com and was planning to have them host my www subdomain.  However, I just learned today that WordPress won't host "www" subdomains.  So, since my old blog was located at a www subdomain, it looks like I'm going to need to redirect any "www" requests to "blog" (or something else).  However, since I'm canceling my old hosting provider account, I don't have any web server where I can configure a 301 redirect.  Can anyone recommend a service provider or other solution for serving up redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a free GoDaddy hosting site that I had never activated before, pointed
my www subdomain to it, and then put a page at the root of the new site that does a redirect to my new blog subdomain.  Good enough.